# Why ajax does not redirect me to another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to redirect the user to another html page after a successful ajax request, but nothing happens. I have to mention the fact that the html page requires authentication, but at the moment the user makes the request he is logged in already.

This is the js:

```
$("form").submit(function (env) {
    env.preventDefault();
    $("#submitbtn").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#form_result").text("");
    var request = JSON.stringify($("#newRequest-form").serializeObject());
    console.log(request);
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/holidays",
        data: request,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function () {
            window.location.href("summary.html");
            /*$("#form_result").text("Submitted succesfully");
            $("form").addClass('hidden');*/
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $("#form_result").text("Error: creating the request. Status: " + error.status + " - " + error.statusText);
            $("#submitbtn").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `window.location = "summary.html";`

Comment: Pleasr try this : window.location.href = "summary.html";

Comment: `window.location.href = "summary.html";`

Comment: As others have hinted at `window.location.href` is a property not a function.

Comment: if you used the developer tools console in your browser, you'd have seen the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: Why does this question have `java` tag?

Comment: @HarshilSharma because OP is a noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.href("summary.html");
```

is not a function, it's a property. Try this:

```
window.location.href = "summary.html";
```